# Unable to Pass a Structure of User Data to GTK Callbacks

Tags: c, gtk3

Although similar questions have been answered regarding this scenario, I'm stuck.

I'm using a structure to pass data to a GTK callback. The structure is defined as

```c
typedef struct List_Stores {
    GSList * list_store_master; 
    GSList * list_store_temporary; 
    List_Builder_Struct * list_builder_struct; 
} List_Store_Struct;
```

I declare the structure in a function.

```c
List_Store_Struct list_store_struct;
```

This structure is passed by reference to a function that makes buttons in a box.

```c
GtkWidget *accounts_buttons_hbox = make_buttons(&list_store_struct);
```

Inside `make_buttons` I connect a signal using

```c
g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(revert), list_store_struct);
```

Inside the function `revert` I want to examine the contents of the structure.

```c
static void revert(GtkWidget* widget, gpointer data) {
    List_Store_Struct* list_store_struct = (List_Store_Struct *) data;

    /* The following lines point to nothing or give the debugger message Cannot access memory at address 0xblahblah */
    GtkListStore * list_store = (list_store_struct->list_builder_struct)->list_store;
    GSList * list_store_master = list_store_struct->list_store_master;
    GSList * list_store_temporary = list_store_struct->list_store_temporary; 
}
```

The debugger shows that the pointer `list_store_struct` points to an empty memory location; I cannot access the structure's members. Furthermore, attempting to access the structure's members results in a segmentation fault.

What is the correct way to pass this structure to the callback so that I can access the structure's members?

Comment: Where are `GSList *list_store_master;` and `GSList *list_store_temporary;` and `List_Builder_Struct *list_builder_struct;` initialized? Currently the members are simply uninitialized pointers. (avoid spaces after `'*'` and `"->"`)

Comment: Those members are initialized shortly before the `struct` is declared. I see the structure's contents where I connect the signal; I lose them inside the callback.

Comment: If after you fill `GtkWidget *accounts_buttons_hbox = make_buttons(&list_store_struct);` the lists are populated, but when you press a button and the `"clicked"` signal triggers the `revert()` callback your lists are gone -- then you likely have a stack smashing problem in code not shown. Because your signal and `revert()` function look fine. Since `List_Store_Struct list_store_struct;` creates the struct on the stack, it will be corrupted if you have any stack smashing that takes place (e.g. an array overrun or similar issues that invokes Undefined Behavior corrupting the stack)

Comment: Excellent advice, and that sounds correct. TBH I'm not entirely clear about reference counters and other memory allocation schemes in GTK, so I probably need to get those straightened out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in my original post, I was attempting to pass to a callback function a pointer to a user-defined structure `List_Store_Struct`. Try as I could, the callback was not able to properly cast the passed `gpointer` to a pointer to `List_Store_Struct`.

I later learned that GTK provides a type [GPtrArray](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/struct.PtrArray.html). While possibly not designed for my use case, passing a void pointer to an instance of `GPtrArray` cleanly casts in the callback, and I was able to access the data at the subsidiary pointers' locations.